# UITTabBarController customization (repositioning tabbar)

Tags: ipad, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to reposition the tab bar in a UITabbarController. I know it's not a great idea but that's what I was asked to do. I managed to move the tabbar to the top of the screen with this:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 68);
```

and it works great. Unfortunately, the content view is not repositioned accordingly.

After I reposition the tab bar, I add the content view and try to adjust it manually, but it doesn't have any effect:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease], 
         nil];
// dummy values for testing.
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 69, 10 , 10);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about moving tabBarController.view's frame down 68 pixels?
You'd have to set the y-coordinate of the tabBar's frame to -68 instead of 0.

If you can't see the tabBar, you might have to set tabBarController.clipsToBounds to NO.

Haven't tried this though.

Comment: I can position the tabbar properly, but I cant get at the rest of the "content view". I thought I might be able to get it with tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0 for instance (for the first selected controller) but modifying the frame values doesn't have any effect..

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. I'm suggesting you change the tabBarController's view's frame. The viewController's views are subviews of that view. Just try this: self.tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 68, 320, 460).

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. What's the logic behind changing tabbarcontroller view? I'm assumign that tabbarcontroller is composed of two views, tabbar and the content view. That doesn't appear to be the case though..

Comment: A viewController (like the tabBarViewController) always has ONE subview. Which is accessed by the view property. I assume the tabBar (view) is a subview of the main view. Does my suggestion do anything or do you see nothing at all? What's your view hierarchy? (navController?)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. Shifting the view that belongs to tab bar controller doesn't seem to do anything. In fact, no matter what frame I set to tabbarController.view, it always seems to reserve the bottom for the button bar.  Right now, the view hierarchy is very simple. Tabbar controller with a simple view to test the layout out..

Comment: Here's a very simple example (based on template): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/551089/tabbartest.zip Instead of using UITabBarController, I subclassed it and named it MyTabBarControoler. In ViewDidLoad, I change the frames of the tabbar and tabbarViewController.view. The tabbar gets repositioned but the controller.view bounds remain the same no matter what I do. You'll notice that the yellow rectangle always remains the same no matter what...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://cl.ly/0H2F1V1K1T3B2X0a3L1c It works except the tabbar isn't tappable. That's because it is outside of it's parent-view bounds. I was just thinking, wouldn't it be easier to just create a tabbar view and position it anywhere you like?